# Php concatenation re-initialize my variable

Tags: php, concatenation, scope

I have two foreach loops one gives `$value1` other gives `$value2`.
 I have defined a string variable `$values` at the top.

```
foreach(...)// get $value1 here
{
   if(strlen($values) > 0)
   $values .=",('".$value1."','')";
   else
   $values .="('".$value1."','')";
}
foreach(...) // get $value2 here
{
   if(strlen($values) > 0)
   $values .=",('','".$value2."')";
   else
   $values .="('','".$value2."')";
}
```

`$values` variable get re initiated.

I get two results one from each loop but I want one result, I want to concatenate all these values to one variable `$values`. What i am doing wrong?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Comment: What is the output you're expecting? and what are you getting?

Comment: Additionally you might want to look into: http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Comment: Can you give a little more info about what the data in is, and what resut you're trying to generate? This sounds like a logic question, not a "how to concatenation" question.

Answer (score 0):

actually if `$values` is not defined before `foreach` it is a local variable. `$values = '';` before `foreach` blocks will make your life easier.

```
$values = '';
foreach(...) {
   if(strlen($values) > 0) {
     $values .=",('".$value1."','')";
   } else {
     $values .="('".$value1."','')";
   }
}
```

you can use `implode` too.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that $values is `globally` initiated, before the 2 `foreach` loops.

```
$values = ''; 
foreach(..){

}
```